# How to fix "implement traits member" error?

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and I am trying to create a tree, but the code is not completed yet. This is what I've done:

```
class Tree {

    class TreeNode(val n: Int, val points: Array[Double],
           val center: Double) extends Tree{
    }
    sealed trait Tree {
    def elem : TreeNode
    }

    def buildTree(points: Array[Double], m: Int): Tree = {
      val center = points(Random.nextInt(points.length))
      val root: Tree = new TreeNode(points.length, points, center)

      println("center is : " + center)
      printNode(root.elem)
      root
    }
}
```

And I am getting the following error:

> class TreeNode must either be declared abstract or implement abstract member elem

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code, as posted, is more than a little confused.

```
sealed trait Tree {
  def elem : TreeNode
}
```

Anything that extends `Tree` will need to define a `TreeNode` that we'll call `elem`. We don't need to define it here because this is a trait.

```
class TreeNode( . . . ) extends Tree {}
```

So a `TreeNode` extends `Tree`, that means that every instance of a `TreeNode` needs an `elem` of type `TreeNode`. But we're defining what a `TreeNode` is. How can we supply the same thing as what we're defining? I can think of only one solution.

```
class TreeNode( . . . ) extends Tree {def elem = this}
```

Now what purpose does `elem` serve? Every instance of `TreeNode` will have a member `elem` that is just a reference to itself. If you have a `TreeNode`, something along the lines of `val tn = new TreeNode(...)`, then `tn.elem` is the same thing as `tn`.

---

Also, why is this all inside `class Tree`? That means you have to have a `Tree` to build a `Tree#Tree`.

```
val tree: Tree = new Tree
val tt: Tree#Tree = tree.buildTree(...)
```

It's all very confused.

Comment: can you suggest a simpler implementation? that answer is very usefull thank you

Comment: Here on StackOverflow a useful answer is up-voted and/or marked as "accepted". As for a simpler implementation, why try to define `Tree`? A tree is just a collection of connected nodes. After you've created the nodes, and connected them, your tree is the same as your root node.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly like your error message said, you can either declare the class being abstract

```
abstract class TreeNode(val n: Int, val points: Array[Double],
                        val center: Double) extends Tree{
}
```

or implement the method

```
class TreeNode(val n: Int, val points: Array[Double],
               val center: Double) extends Tree{
  override def elem: TreeNode = ??? // write here your implementation instead of "???"
}
```

Sorry for being Captain Obvious.

Comment: so if I want to create a new node in my main class with buildTree function the elem method should be:  override def elem: TreeNode = {
      val node = new TreeNode(n,points,center)
      node  }

Comment: @SuzyTros Yes, for example. Or you can write: `override def elem: TreeNode = new TreeNode(n, points, center)`.